# Why the last step of this proof of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality is valid?

Tags: functions, inequality

I have a doubt about the following proof of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality:

> **Proof of the book**
>
> We can prove the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality by letting  \begin{array}
> > P&=a_1^2+a_2^2+\cdots+a_n^2 \\ Q&=a_1b_1+a_2b_2+\cdots+a_nb_n \\
> R&=b_1^2+b_2^2+\cdots +b_n^2 \\ \end{array}  be the coefficients of
>   the quadratic $f(x)=Px^2-2Qx+R$.
>
> Now, since $f(x)$ is a sum of squares, we have $f(x)\ge0$ for any real
>   number $x$. Since $f(x)$ is never negative, it cannot have two distinct
>   real roots, and therefore its discriminant must be non-positive. This
>   gives us $(-2Q)^2-4PR \le 0 ,$ from which we have the desired $PR \ge
>  Q^2.$

Now my question concern the last step of this proof where  the author can claim that the discriminant of $f(x)$ must be $(-2Q)^2-4PR \le 0.$ Why can this be done?

Since $f(x)$ must have $2$ roots, these two roots must both be complex as I can't have one real and one complex root, therefore I can't have that $(-2Q)^2-4PR $ is both less and equal to $0$ as I would allow to have one real root.

What am I missing here?

Comment: This is a known fact about the discriminant of a second degree polynomial

Comment: Can you please tell me to what fact are you referring to ?

Comment: One can have one real double root (and one does when $a_k=\alpha b_k$ for every $k$, for some $\alpha$).

Comment: The two roots can be the same, and real. or they have to both be complex.

Comment: "since f(x)f(x) is a sum of squares"??? It looks to me that $f(x)=[\sum_{k=1}^n (xa_k-b_k)]^2$ is the square of a sum.

Comment: @Jhon Dawkins if you expand you have $f(x)=(a_1x-b_1)^2+(a_2x-b_2)^2 +\cdots +(a_nx-b_n)^2 $ which is a sum of squares. Thanks for the answers and comments . That was a pretty bad conceptual mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formula for the roots of a quadratic states that the roots of $Ax^2+Bx+C$ are
$$ \frac{-B \pm \sqrt{B^2 - 4AC}}{2A}. $$
Suppose that $A,B,C$ are all real. If $B^2-4AC > 0$ then we get two *distinct* real roots. If $B^2 = 4AC$ then there is a double real root. Otherwise there are no real roots.

In this case, there cannot be two distinct real roots $x_1,x_2$, since the function changes sign when crossing $x_1$ (since the roots are single), and so it would be negative at some $x$, contradicting the conclusion that it's always non-negative. So $B^2-4AC>0$ cannot be true, that is, $B^2-4AC \leq 0$.

Comment: so if we have ,for example, $f(x)=(x-2)^2$ I would have that the real roots are $x=2$, $x=2$ ,even though they're the same ?

Comment: That's called a double root.

Comment: Which is why the proof says "cannot have two distinct real roots." It can have two equal real roots. @Mr.Y

Comment: Oh.. shame on me....(*bangs his head against the wall*)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thanks, corrected.